# Unable to register service worker in Firefox, the operation is insecure

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, service-worker

I'm currently porting chrome extension to Firefox, and when I try to register service worker, I'm getting : DOMException: The Operation is insecure

I tried looking for the cookie setting, however, it is not set to "Keep until the browser is closed". I also tried adding a certificate to localhost

I tried registering it by usong both

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('./firebase-messaging-sw.js', { scope: '/' }).then(function(reg) {

    if(reg.installing) {
      console.log('Service worker installing');
    } else if(reg.waiting) {
      console.log('Service worker installed');
    } else if(reg.active) {
      console.log('Service worker active');
    }
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Registration failed with ' + error);
  });
}
```

and using

```
const runtime = require('serviceworker-webpack-plugin/lib/runtime');

if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    const registration = runtime.register();
}
```

Comment: I have this exact issue. Did you ever get it resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this when I tried to add files to the cache which were outside my project directory. I was able to grab the files with a previously registered cache interestingly enough, but could not re-register or install anew.

The solution was to adjust the `Service-Worker-Allowed` header which was set when serving my `ServiceWorker.js` file. Previously it was set to just the project URL/folder, but it needed to be expanded such that it encompassed all the parent folders of files to be cached.

If you're stumped about how to set this header, I used a PHP file to act as the ServiceWorker file; this allows me to set the necessary headers, and then put the ServiceWorker file anywhere on my server (although in the example below the script is in the same folder as the PHP file).

index.php

```
<?php
header("Service-Worker-Allowed: https://www.yoursite.com/");
header("Content-Type: application/javascript");

echo file_get_contents("ServiceWorker.js");
?>
```

Then if your file is in a `ServiceWorker` folder, you can register it with something like this.

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register(
    'ServiceWorker/',
    {scope:"https://www.yoursite.com/"})
.then(function(reg){},function(err){});
```